# React how to add dynamic class to parent element of checked radio/checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my `react`-app, I have a list of checkboxes/radiobuttons - when checked, I want to add an "selected" or "active"-class to the parent `<li>`-tag.

This is my code:

```
const App = ({data}) => {
   const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

   const changeHandler = (e) => {
     setSelected([...selected, e.target.value]);
   };
  
   return (
    <div>
      <ul>
       {data.options.map((option) => (
        <li key={option.id}>
          <div>
            <label>
              <input
                type={data.type === "multiple" ? "checkbox" : "radio"}
                name="answer"
                id={option.id}
                value={option.text}
                onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e)}
                className="chkbox"
              />
            </label>
            <h1>
              {option.title}
            </h1>
          </div>
        </li>
       ))}
     </ul>
   </div>       
  )
}
```

My goal is that the DOM looks like this

```
<ul>
   <li class="selected">*...some option*</li> // checked
   <li>*...some option*</li>
   <li>*...some option*</li>
   <li class="selected">*...some option*</li> // checked
   <li>*...some option*</li>
</ul>
```

so how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add an id to the li tag of `option.id` and then on `changeHandler` use `document.getElementById(option.id)` to get the li element and add the `selected` class to it.

But I think a better approach would be to create a useState variable that stores an object with all the option.id's and add something like `<li key={option.id} className={optionsObj[option.id] && 'active'}>`

Answer (score 0):

With React I prefer to avoid any "direct contact" with the actual DOM and keep using the React DOM. Why not you use something like a "state" variable?

```
<li class={stateVariable}> ... some option </li>
```

In this way, the styling will depend on the value kept at the stateVariable that could be "selected". Since in the future you might get involved with phone apps, I will suggest you to also learn about styling using objects.

Comment: Hmm sounds like the right approach, do you by any chance have any example?

Comment: It is basically like the one at: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html. For styling with objects you could use: https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/react-part-time-react-track/react-fundamentals-part-3/styling-react-css-objects